# React google drive picker image content is broken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api, blob

I have a problem with the response from Google, I get all the file data but when I try to take the content and make it a file in my system **the image is broken** but the other data is OK

I've tried to change the response to Blob even that I know the alt=media do it and still the same issue, also I tried to put mimeType and still no luck

Until a week ago this code worked and for some reason it doesn't work anymore

this is my code,

EDIT:
I find the solution :
This is what I need to add:

```
 const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(fileContent.length);
                            for (let i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
                                uint8Array[i] = fileContent.charCodeAt(i);
                            }
```

```
const requestParams = {
                        'method': 'GET',z
                        'path': `/drive/v3/files/${filesData[i].id}`,
                        'params': {'alt': 'media'} // This parameter requests the file's media (content)
                    };
                    try {
                        const response = await window.gapi.client.request(requestParams);
                        if (response?.body) {
                            const fileContent = response.body;
                            if (fileContent) {
                                const file = new File([fileContent ? fileContent : ""], filesData[i].name);
                                f.push(file);

                            }
                        }
                    }....
```